# Mongoose find recursive nested object by id

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I'm building a note taking app in which there can be as many nested notes inside one another as the user wants, Similar to folder and file structure expect here everything is a note, I have a note model inside it there is a sub_notes array, I want to be able to find a note whether it is a note at the top of the document or nested inside the sub_notes array, I'm passing the id of the note to which I want to add the next note, I have tried graphlookup but when I use the query it is returning an empty array

This is my Note model

```
const noteSchema = new Schema({
  icon: {
    type: String,
  },
  banner: {
    type: String,
  },
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  user_id: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  date: {
    type: Date,
    required: true,
    default: Date.now,
  },
  sub_notes: [
    {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "notes",
    },
  ],
  content: [
    {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "blocks",
    },
  ],
});

module.exports = Note = mongoose.model("notes", noteSchema);
```

This is the query I'm using to find the nested note, The path is a dot seperated string with ids of the notes & the note is the actual note object with the name and other data.

So for ex:

The note

```
{
    id: "123123123",
    sub_notes: [{
        id: "xyz"
    }]
}
```

So the path here will be 123123123.xyz

```
var {
    note,
    path
} = req.body;

var newPath = path.split(".");

const parentNote = Note.findById(newPath[0]);

newPath.splice(0, 1);
console.log(newPath[newPath.length - 1]);
Note.aggregate([{
        $match: {
            $id: newPath[newPath.length - 1]
        }
    },
    {
        $graphLookup: {
            from: "notes",
            startWith: "$id",
            connectFromField: "sub_notes",
            connectToField: "id",
            depthField: "level",
            as: "sub_notes",
        },
    }
]).exec((err, notes) => {
    console.log(notes);
});
```